# Compiling .proto in tensorflow/models/research (not /object_detctio

Tags: python, tensorflow, protocol-buffers, object-detection-api

I'm submitting this to Stack Overflow instead of as a Tensorflow issue because, based on the issues submitted to Tensorflow (e.g. [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/issues/6253)), people are able to get past where I am stuck. The reason I'm submitting in Tensorflow issue format is not because I'm copy-pasting from my own post there, but instead to make my problem clear to you, dear reader. Many thanks in advance for your help.

## **System information**

**What is the top-level directory of the model you are using:** lstm_object_detection

**Have I written custom code (as opposed to using a stock example script provided in TensorFlow):** no

**OS Platform and Distribution (e.g., Linux Ubuntu 16.04):** Ubuntu 18.04

**Python version:** 3.6.7

**Anaconda version:** 4.6.7

**TensorFlow installed from (source or binary):** binary

**TensorFlow version (use command below):** 1.10.0 (also tried with 1.12)

**Bazel version (if compiling from source):** N/A

**CUDA/cuDNN version:** 10.0 (9.2 when using Tensorflow 1.12)

**GPU model and memory:** GTX 2080 ti, 11gb

**Exact command to reproduce:** protoc lstm_object_detection/protos/*.proto --python_out=.

## **Description**

I'm trying to compile the proto files in [this](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/lstm_object_detection/protos) folder, which is part of [lstm_object_detection](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/lstm_object_detection), ultimately to be used with the [Tensorflow Object Detection API](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/object_detection). I am able to compile the proto files in the [object_detection](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/object_detection/protos) folder, as per the Object Detection API installation [instructions](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/installation.md#protobuf-compilation). The Object Detection API tests pass. Sadly though, when I execute the analogous instructions for compiling the lstm_object_detection protos, I get the following error.

```sh
object_detection/protos/input_reader.proto: File not found.
protos/input_reader_google.proto: Import "object_detection/protos/input_reader.proto" was not found or had errors.
protos/input_reader_google.proto:8:10: "object_detection.protos.ExternalInputReader" is not defined.
```

To be abundantly clear, my shell command executed from .../tensorflow/models/research is:

```sh
protoc lstm_object_detection/protos/*.proto --python_out=.
```

And just for kicks I tried:

```sh
protoc \
    lstm_object_detection/protos/*.proto \
    --python_out=lstm_object_detection/protos/
```

I thought maybe lstm_object_detection isn't seeing my object_detection folder, so I added it to my Anaconda path by executing `conda develop .` in models/research/, and just in case also in models/research/object_detection. I also tried adding it to my PYTHONPATH, even though this shouldn't make a difference since Anaconda doesn't use the PYTHONPATH.

**Question:** How do I get these protos outside of the object_detection/protos subdirectory to compile?

Comment: You might have to upgrade your protoc version (check it using "protoc --version"). Make sure your protoc version is greater than 3.2. Also please take a look at this [issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/issues/4002) and let me know if it helps.

Comment: Hey there, thanks for following up, and I apologize for the late response. I haven't worked on this in a bit, but this weekend I'll implement your suggestion and get back to you.

Comment: Update: It works now!  Thanks for your help.

Command was

```
protoc \
    lstm_object_detection/protos/*.proto \
    --python_out=.
```

In the original question, the arguments to `protoc` were incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

Mentioning the Solution in this (Answer) Section (even though it is present in Comments Section), for the benefit of the Community.

The Correct Command is,

```
protoc lstm_object_detection/protos/*.proto --python_out=.
```